# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment while fetching value from JSON.stringify(data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get value from JSON.stringify(data) to textbox but it showing Uncaught ReferenceError error in window console browser. I am confusing that when I am doing alert to the JSON.stringify(data) at that time it shows the value in alert while when I insert that value from JSON.stringify(data) to the textbox at that time it shows the Uncaught ReferenceError in window console browser.

Here is my code

```
  function blurFunction() {
        var c = $find("<%=dropdwn_consignor.ClientID %>");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Booking123.aspx/GetCnorGSTNo",
            data: "{ Param1: '" + c.get_textBoxControl().value + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: "true",
            cache: "false",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(document.getElementById("#<%=txtbx_cnortin.ClientID%>") = JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("something went wrong...!!!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Please help me to solve this issues.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use value property to assign a value. Dont use # in `getElementById()` use `#` in jquery

```
 document.getElementById("<%=txtbx_cnortin.ClientID%>").value = data.D;
```

OR
Just use jquery

```
$("#<%=txtbx_cnortin.ClientID%>").value =data.D;
```

Comment: the value is coming but it is coming in {"D":"-"} this format but just I want - only

Comment: use this JSON.stringify(data).D;

Comment: Check my answer now.

Comment: Sorry to say @Dinesh but again it is showing undefined only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148404/discussion-between-dinesh-and-karan).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set value and get rid of `alert()` its not a debugging tool

```
document.getElementById("#<%=txtbx_cnortin.ClientID%>").value = JSON.stringify(data)
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("#<%=txtbx_cnortin.ClientID%>") = JSON.stringify(data);
```

As you are using jQuery use

```
$("#<%=txtbx_cnortin.ClientID%>").val(JSON.stringify(data))
```